# Populate an entire pre-configured workspace in i3wm

Tags: window-manager, xmonad, i3

Is it possible with I3Wm to populate an entire workspace with determined size, position and commands for each window?

I know I can do `i3-msg "exec xterm -e 'ls; bash'"` to create a new window, but I can't specify his position and size.

Maybe there is also an alternative by declaring via JSON the layout or something like that?

Comment: *"I can't specify his position and size"* I'm not an i3 user, but unless it does something funny, you should be able to use the `-geometry=WxH+X+Y` switch to `xterm`.  The W and H are in characters, the X and Y are in pixels.  Note you could also use the snazzier terminal from (e.g.) XFCE stand-alone if you want, which uses the same style `geometry` spec.  The GNOME terminal may be portable too; KDE's `konsole` definitely is but does not allow you to dictate the geometry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since version 4.8, something like that is part of i3 and there's a [detailed guide](http://i3wm.org/docs/layout-saving.html) on the website, but here's a short version:

Once you've set up a workspace like you want it to be, save its layout with

```
i3-save-tree --workspace <whichever workspace you want> > ~/.i3/layout-ws-<xyz>.json
```

into the file `~/.i3/layout-ws-xyz.json`. You'll then need to edit that file to enable criteria that match windows in the layout.

After that, you can restore that layout with

```
i3-msg "workspace <your workspace>; append_layout ~/.i3/layout-ws--<xyz>.json"
```

This will open placeholder windows on that workspace and when a window matching the criteria enabled in the layout file appears, it will be placed in the corresponding placeholder window.

Comment: Thanks for this tip, I tried it and it works well for saving and restoring workspaces !
But I don't manage to execute any command into these windows (via the JSON). There is only some text written on it without anything else.

Comment: The text in the placeholder windows are the criteria that new windows need to match to be placed into the placeholder window, so if the text in a placeholder window is `class="^Google-chrome$"`, you still need to start an application whose window has that specific class; the application will not be started automatically.

Comment: Got it! I set the right swallows[0].class then launched `i3-msg "workspace 1; append_layout /path/my/layout.json; [class='xterm'] exec xterm` and worked like a charm. This JSON declaration is definitely an awesome feature, thank you!