# I3 load a set of programms in specific layout

Tags: i3

I would like to load a set of programs (browser, terminals, image viewer) in a certain layout (meaning the same tiling).

I tried using `i3-msg split` to start a programm and then apply a tiling to it. Problem is there is a delay between starting the programm and a window comming up, making it very inconsistent.

So is there a way to start up a bunch of programms in the same tiling layout with a single command?

Comment: Have a look at [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152093/populate-an-entire-pre-configured-workspace-in-i3wm/152097#152097) or [this other question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134980/how-do-you-implement-layout-with-the-autostarting-of-applications-in-the-i3-wind)

Comment: almost, I just can't get i3-msg "[class='firefox'] exec firefox" working