# Start a GUI application with a specific x11 instance name

Tags: x11, gui, i3

I have used the following post to create a workspace for my i3 that can be filled with windows.

[Populate an entire pre-configured workspace in i3wm](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152093/populate-an-entire-pre-configured-workspace-in-i3wm)

Now I would like to fill it with specific programs with specific arguments at specific places. For this I would need to start these programs with specific instance names so that I can assign the correct instance names (or classes) for the correct spots.

So basically, how can I start a gui application with a specific instance name so that i3 can find them and place them in the correct spots?

Comment: Perhaps you can go the other way around, as I do in dwm: Find the class of the gui app and use it to place the app wherever you like. Type `xprop WM_CLASS` in a terminal, the cursor will change, then click on the window of the app and xprop will return the wm class of the app (in the terminal). Use this to identify the app. `xprop` can be found in `x11-utils` package in Debian.

Comment: problem is I use the same programm in multiple tiles.

Comment: I found out I can just set RESOURCE_NAME but most programms override it